# Removing message from MSMQ in case of deserialization exception

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

Currently I'm working on widows service which is receiving messages from local private MSMQ. Queue is transactional.

Receiving is done like that:

```
public void ReceiveAndSaveData(MessageQueue queue, MsmqDbContext context)
        {
            var message = new Message();
            try
            {
                using (var tx = new MessageQueueTransaction())
                {
                    tx.Begin();
                    message = queue.Receive(tx);
                    var bodyReader = new StreamReader(message.BodyStream);
                    var jsonBody = bodyReader.ReadToEnd();
                    var messageData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueueMessage>(jsonBody);

                    /*THERE IS SOME DATA PROCESSING*/


                    tx.Commit();
                }
            }
            catch (JsonSerializationException e)
            {
                Logger.WriteError(new LogDetail("Error occured during deserializing incoming data.", e, message.Id));

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.WriteError(new LogDetail("Error occured during saving data to database", e, message.Id));
            }
        }
```

In case of JsonSerializationException, I want to delete this message from current queue. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: [MSDN try-catch-finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch-finally). in the appropriate catch, remove the message and do the commit in the finally block.

Comment: Move the try catch into the using statement and try tx.Abort(); in a failed scenario.

Comment: But can you share code how to remove current message from queue in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Abort()` method and also move the tx-object creation outside the try-catch block.

```
public void ReceiveAndSaveData(MessageQueue queue, MsmqDbContext context)
{
    bool exceptionOccurred = false;
    var message = new Message();
    MessageQueueTransaction tx;
    try
    {
        exceptionOccurred = false;
        using (tx = new MessageQueueTransaction())
        {
            tx.Begin();
            message = queue.Receive(tx);
            var bodyReader = new StreamReader(message.BodyStream);
            var jsonBody = bodyReader.ReadToEnd();
            var messageData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueueMessage>(jsonBody);

            /*THERE IS SOME DATA PROCESSING*/

        }
    }
    catch (JsonSerializationException e)
    {
        Logger.WriteError(new LogDetail("Error occured during deserializing incoming data.", e, message.Id));
        tx.Abort(); //Rolls back the pending internal transaction
        exceptionOccurred = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.WriteError(new LogDetail("Error occured during saving data to database", e, message.Id));
         exceptionOccurred = true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if(!exceptionOccurred)
            tx.Commit();
    }
}
```

> [Abort() MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.messagequeuetransaction?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I've tried this but I got an error in catch block where tx has error Use of unassigned local variable 'tx' and on RemoveCurrent there is an error that MessageQueueTransaction does not contain a definition for 'RemoveCurrent'

Comment: Sorry, What is `new Message()` here? Anyhow, I updated my answer to use the Abort method.

Comment: I've deleted initialization of message variable but I still have problem with tx variable. If I don't initialize it outside try catch block, I can't use it. And only for information. tx.Abort() deletes the message from queue?

Comment: hmm, strange. Can you try `message.RemoveCurrent(tx);` ? `.Abort()` rolls back the internal transaction.

Comment: message.RemoveCurrent(tx) throws same error. Method RemoveCurrent is not known on message object

Comment: If I understand it well. When I abort transaction, message in this transaction is not removed from queue?

Answer (score -1):

Put `tx.Commit()` also inside the `catch` block of the `JsonSerializationException`

Comment: `tx.Commit()` is instantiated in the try block, and therefore not in the same scope as catch (i.e. not avaliable)

Comment: You could move that try-catch block inside the using block, given that the Deserialization operation is performed inside the using statement.